# Center a 1:1 radial background

Tags: html, css, css-gradients

I am trying to give my page a vignette looking background.

```
html {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(249, 249, 249,1),rgba(249, 249, 249,0)); /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(rgba(249, 249, 249,1),rgba(249, 249, 249,0)); /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(249, 249, 249,1),rgba(249, 249, 249,0)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: radial-gradient(rgba(249, 249, 249,1),rgba(249, 249, 249,.66),rgba(249, 249, 249,0)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

I am using rgba because it reduces the banding a little bit.

[image]

But basically I am getting the (exaggerated) image on the right when I want the one on the left. The red represents the visible screen.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I simply needed one more argument, "circle", on all of the gradient calls. For instance:

```
-webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(249, 249, 249,1),rgba(249, 249, 249,0)); /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
```

That with the original code and this at the end:

```
background-position: center;
```

Does exactly what I was describing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an SVG image as background. Using an image provides a way for the browser to know the background aspect ratio. A gradient won't have a known aspect ratio.

I placed the SVG inline in CSS here.

This should do the trick:

<del>**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tca8zzth/1/</del>

**CSS**

```
html {        
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;        
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve"><radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="250" cy="250" r="250" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#F9F9F9"/><stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#F9F9F9;stop-opacity:0"/></radialGradient><rect fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" width="500" height="500"/></svg>');
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

## Update

In order for this to work in Firefox, hashes (`#`) in the data-uri value should be encoded as `%23`.

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tca8zzth/2/

**Updated CSS**

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve"><radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="250" cy="250" r="250" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:%23F9F9F9"/><stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:%23F9F9F9;stop-opacity:0"/></radialGradient><rect fill="url(%23SVGID_1_)" width="500" height="500"/></svg>');
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, I was thinking maybe it would yield better gradients than I am getting from these functions. But your code is not working for me as it is.

Comment: It seems hashes (#) need to be encoded as `%23` when using SVG source in a data-uri in CSS in Firefox. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(249, 249, 249,1),rgba(249, 249, 249,0)); /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(rgba(249, 249, 249,1),rgba(249, 249, 249,0)); /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(249, 249, 249,1),rgba(249, 249, 249,0)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: radial-gradient(rgba(249, 249, 249,1),rgba(249, 249, 249,.66),rgba(249, 249, 249,0)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

"background-size: cover;" for stretch, so increase the height by double and reposition the background to center.

Comment: You don't need to adjust the size. The image is already in its correct aspect ratio! You just have to not manipulate the aspect ratio so the image does not get skewed while setting it as background and center it.

Comment: using "100% 200%" only works assuming the user's window is 2:1. If the user's windows it more square or vertical it's still squished, just vertically. Sauhard, without the size command, the radio matches the window so that wouldn't make it 1:1 either.